# how to append array. or how can i convert model to nsmuttable array

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, objectmapper

in my app i am using alamofire object mapper for use MVC structure. now i am getting one array and i fit it in model class.

here is model class

```
   class OrderDetailSecond: Mappable {

    var id : Int?
    var isRxMedicine : Int?
    var medicineTypeId : String?
    var name : String?
    var orderId : String?
    var price : String?
    var quentity : Int?
    var strength : String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

     func mapping(map: Map) {

        id <- map["id"]
        isRxMedicine <- map["is_rx_medicine"]
        medicineTypeId <- map["medicine_type_id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        orderId <- map["order_id"]
        price <- map["price"]
        quentity <- map["qty"]
        strength <- map["strengh"]
    }
}
```

**NOTE : OrderDetailSecond is an Array**

and now in orderData which is [OrderDetailSecond] i got that array

that array have many object like this

```
(
                            {
                id = 50158;
                "is_rx_medicine" = 1;
                "medicine_type_id" = 2;
                name = "1-11~qwe";
                "order_id" = 50128;
                price = "<null>";
                qty = 12;
                strengh = "12 mcg";
            },
                            {
                id = 50159;
                "is_rx_medicine" = 1;
                "medicine_type_id" = 3;
                name = "1-12~qwe";
                "order_id" = 50128;
                price = "<null>";
                qty = 12;
                strengh = "12 ng/dL";
            }
        );
```

Now i want  only that object whom "is_rx_medicine" = 1;

and want to add that object in any perticular array. So how can i do this?

this is what i tried.

```
for mytest in orderdata
                {
                    if mytest.isRxMedicine == 1
                    {

                        self.myarray?.addObject(mytest)
                    }
                }
```

NOTE: in this mytest is type OrderDetailSecond  like let mytest: OrderDetailSecond

and when i print myarray its show orderpilz.OrderDetailSecond which is my class name.

and when i tried to print like this

```
 print(myarray?.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("quentity"))
```

its give me this error

```
 *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x1461b800 of class 'orderpilz.OrderDetailSecond' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[orderpilz.OrderDetailSecond valueForKey:]
```

possible alternative.

1-> i can make array with object like this and then add value to that object manually and then add that object to array. So let me know how can i do this

Comment: I think you should do  `print(myarray?.objectAtIndex(0).quentity);` ?

Comment: its showing me that value of Type 'Any Object' has no member 'quentity'@iphonic

Comment: That means this `myarray?.objectAtIndex(0)` doesn't have object of class type `OrderDetailSecond`, it will only work if your array has this object type.

Comment: its a syntax by which i map value in id and its working properly.@Fonix

Comment: Do I understand you correctly to have an array of arrays? If so, try .flatmap.filter{} to get the ones you want

Comment: Thanks @iphonic you caught it solved my issue by change in type cast

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter the `orderdata` array instead of looping and checking the condition

```
let filteredArray = orderdata.filter({
    $0.isRxMedicine == 1
})
```

This will return an array of objects that have `isRxMedicine = 1`

**Note:** The type of objects in the `filteredArray` will be same as objects in `orderdata`

Comment: Thanks i solved issue by other way. but even tried this one its also working pretty Well. but can you please explain what is meaning of $0 in syntax.@UditS

Comment: Swift provides shorthand to access parameters in closures. `$0` refers to the first parameter, `$1` second and so on. `filter` method iterates over all the elements in the Array one element at a time. This element is the only parameter of `filter`, thus $0 refers to current element being iterated.