# how to create nsmutable array with object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to create an array like this:

```
"F017A_order_detail" = (
{
    id = 50158;
    "is_rx_medicine" = 1;
    "medicine_type_id" = 2;
    name = "1-11~qwe";
    "order_id" = 50128;
    price = "<null>";
    qty = 12;
    strengh = "12 mcg";
},
{
    id = 50159;
    "is_rx_medicine" = 1;
    "medicine_type_id" = 3;
    name = "1-12~qwe";
    "order_id" = 50128;
    price = "<null>";
    qty = 12;
    strengh = "12 ng/dL";
}

);
```

How can I create an array with object and key value pair?

How can I add values into the object when I want to add?

Comment: what did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: for this reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138622/how-to-append-array-or-how-can-i-convert-model-to-nsmuttable-array?noredirect=1#comment63707943_38138622

Comment: It looks like you want an array of dictionaries, but you could also define a struct and have an array of those. What does your source data look like?

Comment: so how is this question different to your other one?